# Disabling a button on empty <select> list?

Tags: javascript, html, select

`I've created a form that allows a user to enter their details and have their first and last names displayed along with a numerical ID. There is a 'Delete' button allowing the user to remove whatever name they select.

by default, the 'Delete' button should be disabled until the <select> list is populated. If all names are deleted from the list - the 'Delete' button should disable again.

That's where im struggling. I cant get the 'Delete' button to enable when a name is added to the list.

Below is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
    MemberList
    


    <h1>Member List</h1>

    <form method="post" id="_frmFull">

        <label for="lstMembers">Member:</label>
        <select size="10"
                name="lstMembers"
                id="lstMembers">
        </select>


        <button type="button"
                id="addMember"
                name="Add Member">
                Add Member
        </button>
        <button type="button"
                name="Delete Member"
                id="delete">
                Delete Member</button>

            <div id="Modal" class="modal">

                <div class="modal-form">

                    <label for="memTitle">Title:</label>
                    <input list="memTitles" name="memTitles" id="memTitle">

                    <datalist id="memTitles">
                        <option value="Dr">
                        <option value="Mr">
                        <option value="Mrs">
                        <option value="Ms">
                    </datalist>

                    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required="required">

                    <label for="middleName">Middle Name (optional):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName">

                    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required="required">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="Country">Country:</label>
                    <input list="countries" name="Country" id="Country">
                    <datalist id="countries">
                        <option value="Australia">
                        <option value="United Kingdom">
                        <option value="America">
                        <option value="New Zealand">
                    </datalist>

                    <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
                    <select name="Gender" id="Gender">
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                        <option>Other</option>
                    </select>

                    <label for="birthDate">Birthdate:</label>
                    <input type="date"
                           id="birthDate"
                           min="1900-01-01"
                           max="2022-12-31" required="required">

                    <br><br>

                    <div id="resiAddress">

                    <p>Residential Address:</p>

                    <br>

                    <label for="txtResidentialAddress">Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResidentialAddress" oninput="copyAddressFields();">


                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiPostCode">Postcode:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiPostCode">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiSuburb">Suburb:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiSuburb">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiCountry" class="country">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiCountry">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiState">State:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiState">

                </div>

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="chkSynchronizeAddresses">Same as residential </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" required="required" id="chkSynchronizeAddresses" >

                    <div id="postAddress">

                        <p>Postal Address:</p>

                        <br>

                        <label for="txtPostalAddress">Address:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalAddress">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostCode">Postcode:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostCode">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostalSuburb">Suburb:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalSuburb">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostalCountry">Country:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalCountry">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostalState">State:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalState">

                    </div>

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtPhone" class="phone">Phone: (optional)</label>
                    <input id="txtPhone" type="text">


                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtMobile" class="mobile">Mobile: (optional)</label>
                    <input id="txtMobile" type="text">


                    <br><br>

                    <button type="button" name="save" id="save">Save</button>

                    <br><br>

                    <button type="button"
                            name="cancel"
                            id="closeModal">
                            Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>

<script>

    console.log("Log test - please work!!")

    const addBtn = document.getElementById("addMember");
    const modal = document.getElementById("Modal");
    const cancelBtn = document.getElementById("closeModal");
    let chkSynchronizeAddresses = document.getElementById("chkSynchronizeAddresses");
    const _frmFull = document.getElementById("_frmFull");
    let Member = document.getElementById("lstMembers");
    let Delete = document.getElementById("delete");
    let save = document.getElementById("save");
    let fName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    let lName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    let birthDate = document.getElementById("birthDate");

    Delete.disabled = Member.value === 1;



    addBtn.onclick = function (){
        openPopUp();
        console.log('function - correct');
    }

    cancelBtn.onclick = function (){
        let closeTrue = confirm("Close form? You've not saved anything.")
        if (closeTrue === true) {
            closePopUp();
        }
    }

    chkSynchronizeAddresses.onclick = function (){
        console.log("Is this working??");

        if (chkSynchronizeAddresses.checked){
            document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostCode").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalState").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            copyAddressFields();
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").removeAttribute("readonly");
            document.getElementById("txtPostCode").removeAttribute("readonly")
            document.getElementById("txtPostalState").removeAttribute("readonly");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").removeAttribute("readonly");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").removeAttribute("readonly");
        }


    }

    function copyAddressFields () {
        if (chkSynchronizeAddresses.checked){
            document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").value = document.getElementById("txtResidentialAddress").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostCode").value = document.getElementById("txtResiPostCode").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").value = document.getElementById("txtResiSuburb").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostalState").value = document.getElementById("txtResiState").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").value = document.getElementById("txtResiCountry").value;

        }

    }

    let idCount = 0

    save.onclick = function (){

        let fNameValue = fName.value
        let lNameValue = lName.value
        let bDateValue = birthDate.value
        let pCountryValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").value
        let pSuburbValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").value
        let pStateValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalState").value
        let pCodeValue = document.getElementById("txtPostCode").value
        let pAddressValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").value

        if (fNameValue === ""){
            alert("Please enter your first name to proceed");
            return false;
        }

        else
        if (lNameValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your last name to proceed");
            return false;
        } else if (bDateValue === "") {
            alert("Please select a DOB to proceed");
            return false;
        } else if (pCountryValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your country to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pSuburbValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your suburb to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pCodeValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your postcode to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pAddressValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your Address to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pStateValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your state to continue");
            return false;
        } else {

            Member.innerHTML +=
             `<option value= >${idCount} ${_frmFull.firstName.value} ${_frmFull.lastName.value}<option>`
            idCount++
            console.log("check - is increase even working????")

        }

        closePopUp();
        return true;

    }
    function closePopUp() {
        modal.style.display="none";
    }
    function openPopUp() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    Delete.onclick = function removeOption () {
        Member.remove(Member.options);
        console.log("is remove being triggered??")
    }

    if (Member.options.length == ""){
        Delete.disabled = true
    }
    else {
        Delete.disabled = false
    }

</script>
</body>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `Delete` button is not enabling is because the code that is supposed to enable the `Delete` button is only run once, when the page loads.

Assuming that this is the code that is supposed to enable the button:

```js
if (Member.options.length == 0){ // changed from Member.options.length == ""
    Delete.disabled = true
} else {
    Delete.disabled = false
}
```

This code is only run once, when the page loads and the JavaScript code is run. In order to enable the button properly, we need to run this code *every* time that `Member.options.length` changes. One way you can do this is place the code snippet above for disabling/enabling the `Delete` button inside the `onclick` listener for the save button and to re-check every time a new user is saved. You would have to add this snippet into every place in your code where `Member.options.length` could change (inside the listener for the delete button as well).

Full updated code:

```html
        MemberList
    


    <h1>Member List</h1>

    <form method="post" id="_frmFull">

        <label for="lstMembers">Member:</label>
        <select size="10"
                name="lstMembers"
                id="lstMembers">
        </select>


        <button type="button"
                id="addMember"
                name="Add Member">
                Add Member
        </button>
        <button type="button"
                name="Delete Member"
                id="delete">
                Delete Member</button>

            <div id="Modal" class="modal">

                <div class="modal-form">

                    <label for="memTitle">Title:</label>
                    <input list="memTitles" name="memTitles" id="memTitle">

                    <datalist id="memTitles">
                        <option value="Dr">
                        <option value="Mr">
                        <option value="Mrs">
                        <option value="Ms">
                    </datalist>

                    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required="required">

                    <label for="middleName">Middle Name (optional):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName">

                    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required="required">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="Country">Country:</label>
                    <input list="countries" name="Country" id="Country">
                    <datalist id="countries">
                        <option value="Australia">
                        <option value="United Kingdom">
                        <option value="America">
                        <option value="New Zealand">
                    </datalist>

                    <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
                    <select name="Gender" id="Gender">
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                        <option>Other</option>
                    </select>

                    <label for="birthDate">Birthdate:</label>
                    <input type="date"
                           id="birthDate"
                           min="1900-01-01"
                           max="2022-12-31" required="required">

                    <br><br>

                    <div id="resiAddress">

                    <p>Residential Address:</p>

                    <br>

                    <label for="txtResidentialAddress">Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResidentialAddress" oninput="copyAddressFields();">


                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiPostCode">Postcode:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiPostCode">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiSuburb">Suburb:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiSuburb">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiCountry" class="country">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiCountry">

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtResiState">State:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" id="txtResiState">

                </div>

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="chkSynchronizeAddresses">Same as residential </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" required="required" id="chkSynchronizeAddresses" >

                    <div id="postAddress">

                        <p>Postal Address:</p>

                        <br>

                        <label for="txtPostalAddress">Address:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalAddress">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostCode">Postcode:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostCode">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostalSuburb">Suburb:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalSuburb">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostalCountry">Country:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalCountry">

                        <br><br>

                        <label for="txtPostalState">State:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPostalState">

                    </div>

                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtPhone" class="phone">Phone: (optional)</label>
                    <input id="txtPhone" type="text">


                    <br><br>

                    <label for="txtMobile" class="mobile">Mobile: (optional)</label>
                    <input id="txtMobile" type="text">


                    <br><br>

                    <button type="button" name="save" id="save">Save</button>

                    <br><br>

                    <button type="button"
                            name="cancel"
                            id="closeModal">
                            Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>

<script>

    console.log("Log test - please work!!")

    const addBtn = document.getElementById("addMember");
    const modal = document.getElementById("Modal");
    const cancelBtn = document.getElementById("closeModal");
    let chkSynchronizeAddresses = document.getElementById("chkSynchronizeAddresses");
    const _frmFull = document.getElementById("_frmFull");
    let Member = document.getElementById("lstMembers");
    let Delete = document.getElementById("delete");
    let save = document.getElementById("save");
    let fName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    let lName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    let birthDate = document.getElementById("birthDate");
  
    Delete.disabled = Member.options.length == 0


    addBtn.onclick = function (){
        openPopUp();
        console.log('function - correct');
    }

    cancelBtn.onclick = function (){
        let closeTrue = confirm("Close form? You've not saved anything.")
        if (closeTrue === true) {
            closePopUp();
        }
    }

    chkSynchronizeAddresses.onclick = function (){
        console.log("Is this working??");

        if (chkSynchronizeAddresses.checked){
            document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostCode").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalState").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
            copyAddressFields();
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").removeAttribute("readonly");
            document.getElementById("txtPostCode").removeAttribute("readonly")
            document.getElementById("txtPostalState").removeAttribute("readonly");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").removeAttribute("readonly");
            document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").removeAttribute("readonly");
        }


    }

    function copyAddressFields () {
        if (chkSynchronizeAddresses.checked){
            document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").value = document.getElementById("txtResidentialAddress").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostCode").value = document.getElementById("txtResiPostCode").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").value = document.getElementById("txtResiSuburb").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostalState").value = document.getElementById("txtResiState").value;
            document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").value = document.getElementById("txtResiCountry").value;

        }

    }

    let idCount = 0

    save.onclick = function (){

        let fNameValue = fName.value
        let lNameValue = lName.value
        let bDateValue = birthDate.value
        let pCountryValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalCountry").value
        let pSuburbValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalSuburb").value
        let pStateValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalState").value
        let pCodeValue = document.getElementById("txtPostCode").value
        let pAddressValue = document.getElementById("txtPostalAddress").value

        if (fNameValue === ""){
            alert("Please enter your first name to proceed");
            return false;
        }

        else
        if (lNameValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your last name to proceed");
            return false;
        } else if (bDateValue === "") {
            alert("Please select a DOB to proceed");
            return false;
        } else if (pCountryValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your country to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pSuburbValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your suburb to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pCodeValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your postcode to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pAddressValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your Address to continue");
            return false;
        } else if (pStateValue === "") {
            alert("Please enter your state to continue");
            return false;
        } else {

            Member.innerHTML +=
             `<option value= >${idCount} ${_frmFull.firstName.value} ${_frmFull.lastName.value}<option>`
            idCount++
            console.log("check - is increase even working????")
            if (Member.options.length == 0){
                Delete.disabled = true
            }
            else {
                Delete.disabled = false
            }

        }

        closePopUp();
        return true;

    }
    function closePopUp() {
        modal.style.display="none";
    }
    function openPopUp() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    Delete.onclick = function removeOption () {
        Member.remove(Member.options);
        if (Member.options.length == 0) {
          Delete.disabled = true
        }
        else {
          Delete.disabled = false
        }
        console.log("is remove being triggered??")
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

so if i understood correctly you want to toggle a button if a  is populated

In that case you want to keep track of the options

You can use

```
document.querySelectoAll('options')
```

and store it in a variable

then write a function that check if there's a value in that variable and disable or enable the button based on that.

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/skm7bcr6/15/